# Unable to create super user with CustomUser model in Djnago

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Im have created a custom user manager to create users with mobile number in django. But now im unable to create super user. Im getting error **AttributeError: 'CustomUserManager' object has no attribute 'mobile'**. please find the below codes and help out.

Thanks in advance

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from master.models import *



class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

   def _create_user(self, mobile, password=None, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save a User with the given mobile and password."""
       if not mobile:
          raise ValueError('The given mobile must be set')
          mobile = self.mobile
      user = self.model(mobile=mobile, **extra_fields)
      user.set_password(password)
      user.save(using=self._db)
      return user

def create_user(self, mobile, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
    return self._create_user(mobile, password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, mobile, password=None, **extra_fields):
    """Create and save a SuperUser with the given mobile and password."""
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

    return self._create_user(mobile, password, **extra_fields)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   username = None
   mobile = models.CharField(_('Mobile Number'), unique=True, max_length=10)


   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   dob = models.DateField()
   date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_pics')
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   state = models.ForeignKey(State, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   depot = models.ForeignKey(Depot, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   dealer = models.ForeignKey(Dealer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   tse = models.ForeignKey(TSE, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   asm = models.ForeignKey(ASM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   rm = models.ForeignKey(RM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   dgm = models.ForeignKey(DGM, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   bank_ac = models.IntegerField( null=True)
   ifsc = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True)
   bank_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
   aadhar = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=True)
   aadhar_pic_front = models.ImageField(upload_to='aadhar')
   aadhar_pic_back = models.ImageField(upload_to='aadhar')

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'mobile'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

   objects = CustomUserManager()
```

**Error:**

```
deep@Deeps-MacBook-Air vijeta % python3 manage.py createsuperuser
Mobile Number: 9999999999
Password: 
Password (again): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
return super().execute(*args, **options)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site- 
packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
File "/Users/deep/PycharmProjects/vijeta/accounts/models.py", line 39, in create_superuser
return self._create_user(mobile, password, **extra_fields)
File "/Users/deep/PycharmProjects/vijeta/accounts/models.py", line 18, in _create_user
mobile = self.mobile
AttributeError: 'CustomUserManager' object has no attribute 'mobile'
```

Im have created a custom user manager to create users with mobile number in django. But now im unable to create super user. Im getting error **AttributeError: 'CustomUserManager' object has no attribute 'mobile'**. please find the below codes and help out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: reverse this line: `mobile = self.mobile` to be `self.mobile = mobile`

Comment: Thanks a ton ... you saved my many hours